# How do I add autocomplete to Drupal's core search form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm talking about something like jQuery UI's autocomplete, enabled on the core search form.

The handler should return suggested terms from a database query (of short titles I already have saved in an existing field).

I know there are a bunch of contrib modules which allow you to create an autocomplete field, but they don't seem to apply it to the core search form. I may be wrong though.

These are the two articles that I have found that seem most helpful:

http://timonweb.com/how-create-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-drupal-7

http://drupal.org/node/42552

Has anyone else acheived this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Search Autocomplete](http://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) You have to do some configurations. I did not completely get it but initial playing with this gives the idea that it will solve your issue.

Just check its documentation for more details.

Comment: Tried it, but the features promised do not seem to exist.